# glsl shader working differently on different devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I am trying this below shader on my Nexus 7 and I see that it does not work as expected.

http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/index2.html?p=flower

The green rotating background is just missing in nexus 7 ( and also some other devices with GPUs like Adreno 300 series)

Can any one can give any hint as to why this is happening?

Comment: I do not see a "green, rotating background" in that webgl example. Why do you think there should be one?

Comment: derhass, This s theking of image I am talking about http://imgur.com/ISaQFSx . Are you getting the same kind of image?

Comment: Nope. The green stripes in the background are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shader is somewhat broken. I can tweak it to see the green background by changing the original line

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(
    col,
    col-h*0.5+r*.2 + 0.35*h*(1.0-r),
    col-h*r + 0.1*h*(1.0-r),
    1.0);
```

to

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(
    col,
    max(col,0.0)-h*0.5+r*.2 + 0.35*h*(1.0-r),
    max(col,0.0)-h*r + 0.1*h*(1.0-r),
    1.0);
```

since col seems to be <0 for the areas outside of the flower. I do wonder how one *would* see the green background on a conforming implementation.

Comment: Thanks a ton. it worked. By the way how did you fix this. I tried supplying a negative value to col and the green color was still showing up. Maybe  something to do with my Geforce gpu.

Comment: @user1109536: I fixed it exaclty how I described it. Although I'm not sure if this is the best possible fix. Also, I tested with a Geforce GPU, too (660TI, nVidia 331.17 driver, Linux, Firefox 25.0.1).

Comment: If drawing into a floating-point color buffer the default behavior is ***not*** to clamp colors into the range [0.0, 1.0] after outputting from a fragment shader. Now, the default frame buffer is usually fixed-point, and the default clamping behavior for a fixed-point color buffer is to clamp to the range [0.0, 1.0]. If you perform blending with a negative color, you may see something. I have to imagine the OP would understand the difference between a fixed-point and floating-point pixel format though if this were actually the cause of the problem. It sounds more like a driver bug if anything.